# c# -> javascript, Json decoding misses property

Tags: c#, json, encoding, decoding

I have a c# object (below) that I'm trying to send to my javascript.

My problem is, that while I can iterate over the items in the list, I can't get to the string-property ('Period').

Referencing the object in JS shows no property at all. After Json-encoding in c#, I can still see the property just before returning it to caller (hovering over the result variable in below function):

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")]
public JsonResult GetRankingList() {
 Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";
 var user = _userService.GetUserByPrincipal(User);

 // Note, we do this while the user waits as we need to make progress in repeated calls to get the compared ranking list.
 _businessLogicServiceMaintenance.PerformMaintenanceSteps();

 //TODO: Replace with userid (Guid)
 var rankingList = _presenterService.GetRankingListForDisplay(user);

 if (rankingList == null)
  return Json("");

 var result = Json(rankingList);
 return result;
}
```

How on earth can I get past this? Any comments appreciated!

Yours, Anders, Denmark,

```
public class RankingListForDisplay : List<RankingListLine>
{
    public string Period { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How are you creating the JSON from the list and what exactly is the result you are getting before you return it to the caller?

Comment: Hi drs,
Sorry - didn't see the comment.

I've edited the question to show the c# code being called.

Comment: What is the JSON serializer you are using?

Comment: I presume we are talking about the Json(RankingList) call ?
It's System.Web.Mvc.Controller.Json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for taking your time - I found a solution.

I changed above implementation of RankingListForDisplay to the one below. For some reason json likes it way better ;-)

```
public class RankingListForDisplay 
{
    public List<RankingListLine> Lines { get; set; }
    public string Period { get; set; }

    public RankingListForDisplay()
    {
        Lines = new List<RankingListLine>();
        Period = "<Unspecified>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I find it's usually best to favor composition over inheritance, and that's especially true when your model is meant for serialization and deserialization.